# How to fix the null value of this StoredProcedure in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I made a stored procedure for users to login in application but no matter what i tried and watched many stored procedures guides i didn't manage to get values back.

I have tried also with output parameters to get values back and also tried with DatarReader but no values assigned. Debug for some reason ignores the Object values.

In SQL Server with some `DECLARE` method I tried stored seems to work but in C# I get no values.

this is the first stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE spAddUser
@pLogin NVARCHAR(50), 
@pPassword NVARCHAR(50),
@pRole nvarchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO [UsersDetails] (LoginName, PasswordHash, UserRole)
VALUES(@pLogin, HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', @pPassword), @pRole)
END;
```

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spLogin]
    @uname NVARCHAR(50),  
    @pass VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT  LoginName,[PasswordHash],UserRole
    FROM UsersDetails
    WHERE LoginName=@uname AND [PasswordHash]=@pass
END;
GO
```

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Enter Username and Password to Login");
string userLogin = Console.ReadLine();
string passwordLogin = Console.ReadLine();

SqlCommand cmdLogin = new SqlCommand();
cmdLogin.Connection = sqlcon;
cmdLogin.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmdLogin.CommandText = "spLogin";
cmdLogin.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@uname", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = userLogin;
cmdLogin.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@pass", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = passwordLogin;
cmdLogin.Parameters["@uname"].Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;                        

SqlDataReader loginReader = cmdLogin.ExecuteReader();
while (loginReader.Read())
{
    User user = new User
    {
        ID = loginReader.GetInt32(0),
        LoginName = loginReader.GetString(1),
        PasswordHash = loginReader.GetString(2)
    };
    Console.Write(user);
}
loginReader.Close();
```

Comment: Are you reading the hashed password from the console?  `passwordLogin` doesn't appear to be getting hashed before passing it to the procedure.

Comment: I'm no expert on this subject, but it looks like you're trying to use uname as both a parameter and a return value, which probably isn't allowed.

Comment: Why are you first doing `ExecuteNonQuery()` and then `ExecuteReader()`?

Comment: @LouisIngenthron i used this option i found here as long as others but didnt work

Comment: @stickybit sorry my bad. I edited to remove it

Comment: Observations:  `@uname` param shouldn't be set as a ReturnValue from your code.  Just a regular input param.  Also, the datatype for `@pass` param doesn't match between your code and the stored procedure.

Comment: @DBro CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spLogin]
    uname NVARCHAR(50),  
    pass VARCHAR(50)
these are the stored procedure values
the first one is when user signs in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You captured the user's password as a plain text. On the other hand, the password is stored in the database as varbinary. You cannot compare nvarchar with varbinary. You can choose to hash the user's password on the client side. It is also a valid approach. In that case, you should change your SP to receive varbinary as a parameter and your logic will be fine. It means "AND [PasswrodHash]=@pass.

Try inserting a record like shown in the snippet below and change your stored procedure. Notice the user name is 'darko' and the password is 'MyTestPas'

```
CREATE TABLE UsersDetails
(id           INTEGER IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED , 
 LoginName    NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
 PasswordHash VARBINARY(4000) NOT NULL, 
 UserRole     NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

    INSERT INTO UsersDetails
    (loginname, 
     passwordhash, 
     userrole
    )
           SELECT 'darko', 
                  HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', 'MyTestPas'), 
                  'admin';
    --Check the result 
    SELECT *
    FROM UsersDetails;

    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spLogin] @uname NVARCHAR(50), 
                                     @pass  VARCHAR(50)
    AS
        BEGIN
            SELECT ID, 
                   LoginName, 
                   [PasswordHash], 
                   UserRole
            FROM UsersDetails
            WHERE LoginName = @uname
                  AND [PasswordHash] = HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', @pass);
        END;
    GO
```

Change your .NET code by using the following snippet. Note, for the sake of simplicity I replace reading the user name and the password with constants. The second note is that you have to change the connection string.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ConsoleApp21
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            // these are read from the command line as the plain text
            const string userLogin = "darko";
            const string passwordLogin = "MyTestPas";

            // Change to match your connection string
            var sqlcon = new SqlConnection("Integrated Security = true; Initial Catalog = your database; Server = your server");
            sqlcon.Open();
            var cmdLogin = new SqlCommand
            {
                Connection = sqlcon, CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure, CommandText = "spLogin"
            };
            cmdLogin.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@uname", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = userLogin;
            cmdLogin.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@pass", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = passwordLogin;


        var loginReader = cmdLogin.ExecuteReader();
        while (loginReader.Read())
        {
            var user = new User
            {

                LoginName = (string)loginReader["LoginName"],

                UserRole = (string)loginReader["UserRole"]
            };
            Console.Write($"{user.LoginName}({user.UserRole})");

        }
        loginReader.Close();
        Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class User
    {
        public string UserRole { get; set; }
        public string LoginName { get; set; }
        public Byte PasswordHash { get; set; }


        public int Id { get; set; }


    }
}
```

Comment: It did work actually.
my main purpose was to see that user did managed to login sucessfully!
Why in stored procedure did you ADD this:
AND [PasswordHash] = HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', @pass);
and why in class ID setter needs to be internal?

Comment: You captured the user's password as a plain text. On the other hand, the password is stored in the database as varbinary. You cannot compare nvarchar with varbinary. You can choose to hash the user's password on the client side. It is also a valid approach. In that case, you should change your SP to receive varbinary as a parameter and your logic will be fine. It means "AND [PasswrodHash]=@pass. And finally, there is no need that setter is internal. That is just an R# suggestion which I did not notice yesterday.